# What is the concept of attached disk and the default min/max disk space provided by the AWS Lightsail container service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have created an AWS Lightsail container service (Micro). Uploaded a docker image and made the deployment.

The project is a web api that has a POST endpoint that expects a file, it will save the file in a folder, extract the keywords from the file, delete the file and reply with JSON response.

I think that - when the container service restarts (for example due to API crash or whatever reason), then the container service will create a new instance of the image and hence the disk will get reset.

I am not able to locate any documentation regarding the concept of attached disk and what is the default min/max disk space provided by the AWS Lightsail container service?

Answer (score 1):

> when the container service restarts (for example due to API crash or whatever reason), then the container service will create a new instance of the image and hence the disk will get reset.

The container service has only ephemeral (temporary) storage by default.

When you want to persist a filesystem in a container service, you have to use some persistent storage.

If you want to use "local" filesystem, you can mount an [EFS storage](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/efs-and-lightsail/). Another option is to store the files directly to an S3 bucket if it is feasible for you.

S3 sand EFS are elastic - practically without any size limits.

If you want to mount a block storage (EBS - a disk), I'm not sure (I doubt) that it is possible in a LightSail container.

Comment: What is the capacity of the default ephemeral (temporary) storage?

Comment: Interesting, it's not even mentioned in the documentation (I'd assume it may depend on the image size). If you have your code running inside, you may check yourself. The idea with containers is that you are not suppose to use the local container fs as a persistent storage. You either store the data in a DB, S3 or EFS. It is possible to attach an EBS disk to a lightsail instance, not container, there you could use up to 64TB.

Comment: I agree but I need some deterministic figure of the minimum supported disk space as my Api has to save the file locally to be able to process the file, and although the Api subsequently deletes the file, I am looking for official doc regarding min space assurance.